# Trying to solve Advent of Code 2015 Day 06 with a bitlist

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I'm using Advent of Code 2015 to practice. I tried to solve [Day06](http://adventofcode.com/2015/day/6) with a bitlist rather than a list of coordinates and status, but it does not compute the right value and I can't understand if there's a fault in the logic or in the implementation.

Here's the code:

```haskell
module Day06 where

import Data.Bits
import Data.Ix
import Data.List

parse :: String -> [Int]
parse a =
  let (c1,c2) = break (==',') a
  in range (read c1, read (tail c2))

mFlatten :: String -> String -> [Int]     
mFlatten x y =
    [ a + b * 1000 | a <- parse x, b <- parse y]

action :: (Bits b, Num b) => b -> [[Char]] -> b          
action state instruction = case instruction of
      ["toggle", a, _, b] -> foldl' complementBit state $ mFlatten a b
      ["turn","on", a, _, b] -> foldl' setBit state $ mFlatten a b
      ["turn","off", a, _, b] -> foldl' clearBit state $ mFlatten a b

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- readFile "input"
  print $ popCount $ (foldl (\ acc x -> action acc $ words x) 0 (lines input) :: Integer)
```

I have a few questions:

1. Is there a more idiomatic way to write this code?
2. How can I improve performances?

and most important

3. Did I make any mistake that would cause the program to compute the wrong result? I'm thinking something such as Type conversion maybe, but it's possible I'm missing something very obvious.

(To avoid having to login to have a look at the input, you can find it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevejb71/haskell-advent-of-code/master/Day6/input.txt))

Comment: Would it be possible to post the problem description (or at least a summary of the problem)?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of (simple) input and some expected output, and what you get instead?  A small example with maybe two or three instructions only.

Comment: if your (c1,c2)  are such that c1 > c2 you'll get an empty list in `parse`
(`range` will give you an empty list if  c1<c2)

Comment: @QuinnWilson Yes you're right, normally it should be checked, but it's in the nature of the problem that c1 will always been < c2. I'll double check that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you don't use `Int` due to overflow. Use `Integer` instead, which can grow arbitrarily large.
2. As I understand it, the problem asks you to turn on/turn off a rectangular area between opposite corners (a,b), (A,B). I think you interpret the two tuples as rectangle [a..b]x[A..B] but it should be [a..A]x[b..B] (assuming a<=A, b<=B)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am using the `bit` function (in the form of `complementBit`, `setBit` and `clearBit`) which is the same as `shiftL`: `shiftL 1 x` is the same as `bit x`, and `complementBit x y` == `x .|. (bit y)` == `x .|. (shiftL 1 y)`, so I'm not sure that's the problem. I will however try to replace `Int` with `Integer`.

Comment: @haskeller: True, my bad. As I understand it, the problem asks you to turn on/turn off a rectangular area between opposite corners (a,b), (A,B). I think you interpret the two tuples as rectangle [a..b]x[A..B] but it should be [a..A]x[b..B] (assuming a<=A, b<=B)

Comment: Yes that's it!! Thank you! What an oversight from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Long got it right, big oversight from my side. Here's the working code:

```
module Day06 where

import Data.Bits
import Data.List

parse :: String -> (Int,Int)
parse a =
  let (c1,c2) = break (==',') a
  in (read c1, read (tail c2))

mFlatten :: String -> String -> [Int]     
mFlatten a b =
    let (x1,y1) = parse a
        (x2,y2) = parse b
    in [ x + y * 1000 | x <- [x1..x2], y <- [y1..y2]]

action :: (Bits b, Num b) => b -> [[Char]] -> b          
action state instruction = case instruction of
      ["toggle", a, _, b] -> foldl' complementBit state $ mFlatten a b
      ["turn","on", a, _, b] -> foldl' setBit state $ mFlatten a b
      ["turn","off", a, _, b] -> foldl' clearBit state $ mFlatten a b

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- readFile "input"
  print $ popCount $ (foldl (\ acc x -> action acc $ words x) 0 (lines input) :: Integer)
```

Thanks very much!